# "Content Areas" in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: content

What exactly does the term, 'content area' mean in Sharepoint 2010. Does it mean web apps, site collections, sites or general content available. Are there any others 'areas' in Sharepoint similar to 'content area'?

Answer (score 1):

Content Area is sometimes used to refer to the PlaceholderMain content placeholder in the SharePoint master page that merges the main content of pages into the master page.

Answer (score 0):

Content area is nothing but the concept of master pages and content pages.
For example a teams site in sp 2007 , the top navigation , footer navigation and the quick launch come under master page . The area where you add new webparts is content area .

In particular, a master page defines common elements that are to be used across many different pages (such as the top banner) as well as site navigation controls. The layout defined in a master page can then be used across many different pages that link to it. In ASP.NET terminology, a page that links to a master page is known as a content page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892189(v=office.12).aspx